# Rust, PyO3, and return a "simple" internal iterator

Tags: rust, pyo3

Older answers use the outdated `#[pyprotocol]` workflow for magic methods. I think PyO3 has matured a bit, so I'm asking this again.

I have a simple struct

```rust
#[pyclass]
struct Outer {
  inner: Vec<i32>
}
```

In the PyO3 documentation, if I want to make `Outer` iterable, I need to implement `__iter__`, which needs to return something that implements both `__iter__` and `__next`. So in the documentation, they provide a

```rust
#[pyclass]
Iter {
  iter: std::Vec::IntoIter<i32>
}

#[pymethods]
impl Iter {
    fn __iter__(slf: PyRef<'_, Self>) -> PyRef<'_, Self> {
        slf
    }

    fn __next__(mut slf: PyRefMut<'_, Self>) -> Option<bool> {
        slf.inner.next()
    }
}
```

and then my `Outer` will have

```rust
pub fn __iter__(slf: PyRef<'_, Self>) -> PyResult<Py<Iter>> {
    let iter = Iter {
        inner: slf.config.clone().into_iter(),
    };
    Py::new(slf.py(), iter)
}
```

Is there no shorter way to do this? For example, `Vec<i32>`, thanks to PyO3, will implement the necessary traits for automatic conversion into a python list. Aren't there similar shortcuts so that I wouldn't have to implement that whole `Iter` struct and could just do something like

```
fn __iter__(...) {
  self.inner.iter().cloned()
}
```

and maybe wrap it in the correct `PyResult` or whatever things? I'm *fine* doing it with the extra struct, it just feels an extra step that might not be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return an existing Python iterator (for example, a list iterator) from `__iter__()`. This will be easier because you can use PyO3 existing machinery for converting Rust collections to Python collections, but slower because you need to copy the whole Rust collection to a Python collection:

```rust
use pyo3::types::PyIterator;

#[pymethods]
impl Outer {
    pub fn __iter__<'py>(&self, py: Python<'py>) -> PyResult<&'py PyIterator> {
        PyIterator::from_object(self.inner.to_object(py).into_ref(py))
    }
}
```

Comment: Got it. In this case I don't want to make that speed/convenience tradeoff, but it's nice to know this option.